# Dynamically adding to the queue of RXJS Observables

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

The objective is to dynamically add the queue of HTTP requests *and* handle the queue as one request. Let me show the status quo first.

**component.ts**

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.touched
        .pipe( 
             filter(res => !!res),
             takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
         )
        .subscribe(() => this.onSave());
}

public onSave(): void {
    this.busy = true;
    this.service.save()
        .pipe(finalize(() => this.busy=false))
        .subscribe(() => this.isInSync = true);
}
```

**service.ts**

```
public touched: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
public saved: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

public save(): Observable<ApiResponse> {

    const data = this.getDirtyData();

    const payload = data.map(( d: Data) => {
       /** [...] */
    });

    const reqOptions: HttpRequest<any> = this.api.setRequestOptions( '/url', payload );
    return this.api.apiHttpRequest(reqOptions)
        .pipe(
            map( resp => resp.data),
            tap( resp => this.saved.next(resp))
        );

}
```

This is what it looks now. It works fine - but what I need is to be able to form a queue of those http requests if the user fires that `onSave` method multiple times, so that component gets to `finalize` the Observable only once. If I use it the way it is, the component subscribes to the observable multiple times and so sets `this.busy` and `this.isInSync` prematurely.

Any suggestions on how to solve this in an elegant way?

Comment: Can you try to explain what you're trying to achieve more in depth? Reading the code doesn't really help me understand but if you explain clearly I might be able to help :)

Comment: The question is open ended now. Say the user starts firing the `onSave()` method and for each trigger we queue an HTTP request, what is the threshold criteria to break the queue? In other words, when do you wish to close the close and start triggering the HTTP requests? Also are the requests to be fired in parallel or serial?

Comment: The user can trigger this `onSave` action multiple times, one after another. Each time a http request should be formed and added to the queue. The requests should be fired one after another not in parallel. The only reason to stop the queue from executing  is a server error. My objective is to set `busy` and `isInSync` variables only once, as they are used in the interface to show the state of data. If the first request is closed, `busy` is set to true, the interface says "Alright!", although there is a second request still ongoing. And this is a problem.

Comment: Think of it as when you edit a google document and it constantly saves all your changes (as you type, delete, add, etc). This is my objective, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
public onSave(): void {
    this.busy = true;
    this.service.save()
        .pipe(finalize(() => this.busy=false))
        .subscribe(() => this.isInSync = true); <--------------
}
```

You can think of it as a code smell. When you call subscribe, that's where the reactive programming ends. This should not happen until the very last end of what you're trying. In this case, as you `subscribe` within a method that is called multiple time, you'll loose the ability to queue the requests as you'd like.

I think what you're trying to achieve can be represented with the following code (mix of mock for the HTTP call and actual stream logic):

```
const mockHttpRequest = (someParam: any) =>
  of(`Result: ${someParam}`).pipe(delay(1000));

const change$$ = new Subject<any>();

const queue$ = change$$.pipe(concatMap(change => mockHttpRequest(change)));

const isSyncing$ = combineLatest([
  change$$.pipe(
    map((_, index) => index),
    startWith(-1)
  ),
  queue$.pipe(
    map((_, index) => index),
    startWith(-1)
  )
]).pipe(
  map(([changeIndex, queueIndex]) => changeIndex !== queueIndex),
  distinctUntilChanged()
);

isSyncing$.subscribe(console.log);
```

A little bit of explanation on this:

```
const mockHttpRequest = (someParam: any) =>
  of(`Result: ${someParam}`).pipe(delay(1000));
```

Simply mock an HTTP call with a delay

```
const change$$ = new Subject<any>();
```

The subject that you should call whenever a change happens

```
const queue$ = change$$.pipe(concatMap(change => mockHttpRequest(change)));
```

As its name says: This is the queue for all the HTTP calls. They'll happen one by one and won't be done in parallel.

```
const isSyncing$ = combineLatest([
  change$$.pipe(
    map((_, index) => index),
    startWith(-1)
  ),
  queue$.pipe(
    map((_, index) => index),
    startWith(-1)
  )
]).pipe(
  map(([changeIndex, queueIndex]) => changeIndex !== queueIndex),
  distinctUntilChanged()
);
```

This observable will let you know the current status of the app: Whether it's syncing some data or not. To do this, we compare how many items have successfully gone out of the HTTP queue with how many saves attempts where made. If it's the same number we know we're in sync otherwise we're syncing.

The `distinctUntilChanged` is necessary because if we emit let say 2 changes really quickly and the second one we try to send it before the last one comes back, the observable `isSyncing$` would emit twice `false` before emitting `true` once they're both done. With `distinctUntilChanged` we ensure that it emits only once `false` and only once `true` when that's the case.

Finally to test this we can do the following:

```
// simulate events happening when a user type at different times
// on the document to test our code
change$$.next('This is some initial text...');

setTimeout(() => {
  change$$.next('This is some initial text... And now with some other edit...');
}, 1500);

setTimeout(() => {
  change$$.next(
    'This is some initial text... And now with some other edit... And a quick one before previous is finished processing...'
  );
}, 1500);

setTimeout(() => {
  change$$.next(
    'This is some initial text... And now with some other edit... And a quick one before previous is finished processing... And a last one'
  );
}, 4500);
```

and it should output

```
false
true
false
true
false
true
false
```

Note that the ones happening at the same time (1500) don't emit twice it's just that the status `isSyncing$` stays true for a bit longer than the other as the 2 calls are made one after another

```
false
true
false
true <--- this one
false
true
false
```

If you want to play with this, here's a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vtnk6z?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Thanks, pal! That's exactly what I was looking for. I had to modify a bit with `takeUntil()` and move the `busy` from `finalize()` to `subscribe()`, but it does what it supposed to do. Great.

Comment: @maxime1992 -- hope you don't mind if I add on to this. This *almost* solves my own use case, but I have a slightly different requirement. I don't want to queue up MULTIPLE http calls -- I want a maximum of one request to be waiting.

The scenario is where the user makes changes which trigger a save, then while that save request is executing, they make more changes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your design, `combineLatest` or `forkJoin` may be good choices for you. for example, if you have more than 1 service calls and you want to treat them as 1 request call:

```
forkJoin({
  serviceCall1: this.httpService1(input1:string...);
  serviceCall2: this.httpService2(input2:string...);
}).pipe().subscribe();
```

forkJoin waits all the requests inside to be completed and then emits their value. combineLatest emits whenever one of the requests resolve.

Also in rxjs7 there are `connect`, `connectable` which solves it better but not compatible older versions of Angular.

**for further information** : [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest)

Comment: forkJoin seems fitting to me - I just can't wrap my head around on how I get that subscription within onSave method to subscribe only once instead of multiple times.

Comment: Did you try to do it on lifecycle hooks?

Comment: Try to do exactly what? :)

Comment: Oh, now I understood, I strongly reccomend you to look at 'defer' operator of rxjs.